# e.g. How to fix error in importing multiple functions from a .py file VSCode

Tags: python, function, visual-studio-code, import

today I've decided to start using VSCode for programming in python. I've encountered a problem which I am not able to face off, and this is the importing of several functions from a .py file to an .ipynb one: it seems like it has no problem in importing the "first" function of the .py file but it is not able to import the others.

I've create a first file "Try.ipynb" and a second one "Functions.py" which are in the same directory, namely "Kushike".
The file "Functions.py" is as it follows:

```
from typing import List
import pandas as pd 

def multiread(filenames : List[str]) -> List[str]:
    '''
    Read a list of datasets and return them into a list'
    :param filenames -> A list containing the filenames of the datasets we want to read
    :return -> A list of pandas DataFrame objects corresponding to files in filenames
    '''
    df_list = []
    for file in filenames:
        if file.split('.')[-1] == 'csv':
            df_list.append(pd.read_csv(file, index_col = [0]))
        else:
            df_list.append(pd.read_excel(file))
    return df_list

def six():
    print(6)
```

whereas the file "Try" is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from Functions import *

df1, df2 = multiread(['df_1.csv, df_2.csv'])

six()
```

When running it I have no problems with multiread, which correctly generates the two dataframes, but the function "six" doesn't work giving the error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8084/1267120857.py in <module>
----> 1 six()

NameError: name 'six' is not defined
```

Hope you can help me.

Kushike

Comment: what if you run this from the command line

Comment: When I tried executing your code,  its working. try saving both files(if necessary, restart) and run again and check if your vs code interpreter is using default python interpreter or virtual one. If your problem still exists, provide your sample files data.

Comment: @Kushike I can run it correctly too. It's weird on the logic, as you can rename the function of 'multiread' to 'six'. Agree with Pranta Palit, make sure save the file and reopen the VSCode.